Codeigniter 3: Required permissions are not granted. At least one of these permissions must be granted
Authenticated successfully. Access Token:
I have successfully authenticated the access token, but fetching data have a problem
Failed to fetch employees. Response: {"result":null,"targetUrl":null,"success":false,"error":{"code":0,"message":"Required permissions are not granted. At least one of these permissions must be granted: H r 2 0 1 employees","details":null,"validationErrors":null},"unAuthorizedRequest":true,"__abp":true}
here is my EmployeeController.php (controller):
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class EmployeeController extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // Load the session library
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    // Function to authenticate the user and get the access token
    public function authenticate() {
        $url = 'http://172.16.0.177:5101/api/TokenAuth/Authenticate';

        $data = json_encode(array(
            'userNameOrEmailAddress' => 'myusernamehere',
            'password' => 'mypasswordhere',
            'twoFactorVerificationCode' => '',
            'rememberClient' => true,
            'twoFactorRememberClientToken' => '',
            'singleSignIn' => true,
            'returnUrl' => '',
            'captchaResponse' => ''
        ));

        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Accept: application/json',
        ));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        if (curl_errno($curl)) {
            echo 'cURL Error: ' . curl_error($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            return;
        }
        curl_close($curl);

        $result = json_decode($response, true);

        if (isset($result['result']['accessToken'])) {
            $this->session->set_userdata('access_token', $result['result']['accessToken']);
            echo "Authenticated successfully. Access Token: " . $result['result']['accessToken'];
        } else {
            echo "Authentication failed. Response: " . print_r($result, true);
        }
    }

    // Function to ensure valid token, authenticating if needed
    private function ensureAuthenticated() {
        if (!$this->session->userdata('access_token')) {
            $this->authenticate();
        }
    }

    // Function to fetch employees
    public function fetchEmployees() {
        $this->ensureAuthenticated(); // Ensure user is authenticated
        $accessToken = $this->session->userdata('access_token');
        $url = 'http://172.16.0.177:5101/api/services/app/HR201EmployeesV2/GetAll';

        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        if (curl_errno($curl)) {
            echo 'cURL Error: ' . curl_error($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            return;
        }

        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($curl);

        // Decode the response
        $data = json_decode($response, true);

        // Check for successful response
        if ($httpCode == 200 && isset($data['result'])) {
            $this->load->view('employee_list', ['employees' => $data['result']]);
        } else {
            // If unauthorized, re-authenticate and retry
            if ($httpCode == 401) {
                $this->authenticate(); // Attempt to re-authenticate
                return; // Prevent recursive calls
            } else {
                log_message('error', 'Failed to fetch employees. Response: ' . print_r($data, true));
                echo 'Failed to fetch employees. Response: ' . json_encode($data);
            }
        }
    }

    // Function to check user permissions
    public function checkUserPermissions() {
        $this->ensureAuthenticated(); // Ensure user is authenticated
        $accessToken = $this->session->userdata('access_token');
        $url = 'http://172.16.0.177:5101/api/services/app/Permission/GetAllPermissions'; // Endpoint to get permissions
    
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
        ));
    
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        if (curl_errno($curl)) {
            echo 'cURL Error: ' . curl_error($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            return;
        }
    
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($curl);
    
        // Decode the response
        $data = json_decode($response, true);
    
        if ($httpCode == 200 && isset($data['result'])) {
            echo "User Permissions: " . print_r($data['result'], true);
        } else {
            if ($httpCode == 401) {
                $this->authenticate(); // Attempt to re-authenticate
                return; // Prevent recursive calls
            } else {
                echo 'Failed to fetch user permissions. Response: ' . json_encode($data);
            }
        }
    }
    
}

I want to show all the employees within my view employee_list.php
